# building structure for employee office relation

Tags: mysql

I have a table defined like this

```
  empid   fromdate        todate       office_ID
    1     2012-03-01      2014-04-2      1
    1     2014-04-03      ----           2
    2     2012-03-01      2014-04-2      2
    3     2012-03-01      2014-04-2      1
```

If the employee is currently working at some office then `todate` will be not known hence it is null. This logic can be changed if you suggest something better.

From this table I want to fetch an employee's location(s) for a given month. For example, for May 2005 where was employee 1? For that I have designed this query

```
select * 
from tbl_emp_office 
where (year(From_date)*100 + month(From_date)) < '201505'
```

This structure is not giving the exact solution to my problem. Can you suggest more suitable structure for this?

**EDIT**
`fromdate` has data type Date.

Answer (score 2):

What "datatype" is `From_date`?  Assuming it is DATE or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, then this will find records *before* May, 2015:

```
select * from tbl_emp_office where From_date < '2015-05-01';
```

This will find records for *only* May, 2015:

```
select * from tbl_emp_office 
    where From_date >= '2015-05-01'
      and From_date  < '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

If you are using VARCHAR, well *don't*.

**Edit** to answer "Where was emp#1 working during May, 2015?"

```
SELECT  office_id
    FROM  tbl_emp_office
    WHERE  empid = 1
      AND  From_date < '2015-05-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH -- Started before/during May
      AND  ( To_date IS NULL          -- Still working there
         OR  To_date >= '2015-05-01'  -- Left during/after May
           );
```

Note:  If he worked in multiple offices during May, this will produce multiple rows.

Comment: yes from_date is Date Data type field